# Code calling TWAIN_32.DLL crashes inside Visual Studio, but runs perfectly outside

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, twain

I have a class communicating with the TWAIN_32.DLL, I want to capture images from a camera or a scanner. when I want to acquire an image, I call the TWAIN_32.DLL. The funny thing is: The call crashes, when I run the project from within the IDE (Visual Studio 2010).

The exception is

```
System.Runtim.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005)
```

In particular, I am calling the TWAIN UI.

Now the fun part: When I call this EXE from outside the IDE, everything works.

I could not find anything specific on this topic in the internet.

Any ideas what could cause this? Any clues why this only happens inside the IDE? What is different in Visual Studio compared to outside? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Permission issue? What if you run Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: I'm quite sure I tried that. But I'll give it another try though. This is about the only idea left. Thanks.

Comment: if that didn't solve it, could you check wether your application is running in the same architecture (x86 OR x64) and not switching depending on how it was started? Also what happens if you start your application and attach Visual Studio to your process BEFORE scanning?